# How to add a year to a column of dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am attempting to add a year to a column of dates in a pandas dataframe, but when I use `pd.to_timedelta` I get additional hours & minutes. I know I could take the updated time and truncate the hours, but I feel like there must be a way to add a year precisely. My attempt as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.DataFrame({'date':['20170101','20170102','20170103']})
dates['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dates['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
dates['date2'] = dates['date'] +  pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='y')
dates
```

yields:

```
Out[1]: 
    date        date2
0   2017-01-01  2018-01-01 05:49:12
1   2017-01-02  2018-01-02 05:49:12
2   2017-01-03  2018-01-03 05:49:12
```

How can I add a year without adding 05:49:12 HH:mm:ss?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
In [99]: dates['date'] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
Out[99]:
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-02
2   2018-01-03
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

leap year check:

```
In [100]: pd.to_datetime(['2011-02-28', '2012-02-29']) + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)
Out[100]: DatetimeIndex(['2012-02-28', '2013-02-28'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Good answer. Link to [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects). Mind typos! That it is `years`, not `year`, or get a nasty out of bounds error.

Answer (score 4):

You can normalize via [`pd.Series.dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
dates['date2'] = (dates['date'] +  pd.to_timedelta(1, unit='y')).dt.normalize()
```

Comment: This no longer works in new versions of pandas.

Answer (score 2):

Or convert `datetime` to `date`

```
dates['date'] = dates['date'].apply(lambda a: a.date())
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This works if you don't care about leap years, etc. Otherwise see jp_data_analysis's answer.

You can use 365 and `unit='d'`:

```
pd.to_timedelta(365, unit='d')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I have a large number of dates and need to account for leap years. I'd like to preserve calendar date to account for holidays (New Year's day, Christmas, etc.)

Comment: Gotcha. jp_data_analysis's answer should work [and be fast] then.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the components of a date (year, month and day) using code of the form `dataframe["column"].dt.component`.

For example, the month component is `dataframe["column"].dt.month`, and the year component is `dataframe["column"].dt.year`.

Comment: Good to know, but not useful if you need to modify: `ValueError: modifications to a property of a datetimelike object are not supported. Change values on the original.`