# Adding integer to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe where I am trying to add a predefined integer value to a datetime.

```
id  start date term

ab  13-09-2017   6
```

What I would like to do is add the integer term `6` as years to the datetime.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Comment: Quick search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796729/how-to-add-a-year-to-a-column-of-dates-in-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.DateOffset` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['ab'], 'startdate':['13-09-2017'], 'term':[6]})
df['startdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['startdate'])

df['startdate'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['startdate'] + pd.DateOffset(years=int(x['term'])), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
cccid startdate  term                                                                                                                         
0  ab 2023-09-13     6
```

Comment: I would suggest timedelta, but this answer is better, thanks for sharing!